# Siglent SDS Oscciloscope VISA disconnection

Tags: usb, oscilloscope, python, scpi

I'm currently connecting my Siglent SDS1202X-E Digital Storage Oscilloscope to my lab PC using a USB cable. I took advantage of the VISA interface that it has and used PyVISA package to write script for automated testing. However, although the Python scripts worked fine, the scope kept disconnecting from the PC occasionally. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I do the same thing with my Siglent scope without any issues.  Did you update the scope with the latest firmware?  Is there a VISA package on your PC other than PyVISA?

Comment: Use a good usb cable with a ferrite on it, and a good pc with a decent USB port. If you have lots of EMI or high power loads switching it could be from that.